# I want to regularly push files to AWS S3 from an on-prem server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I generate some files(size of the order KBs) periodically on an on-prem server. I want to push them to s3 as soon as they are generated. How do I go about managing the accesses?

I'm using the boto3 package of python to do so. How do I manage access, as in do I create a new IAM role? If so, how to specify the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few requirements here:

- You need something to **'trigger' the upload**. This could be a cron job / scheduled task, or it could be specifically triggered by whatever process is generating the files
- You could then use either the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command to **upload the files** (either `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync`), or you could write your own program as you suggested.

The AWS CLI or your own program will require AWS credentials. The recommended method would be:

- **Create a User in IAM** and make note of the credentials (Access Key, Secret Key)
- **Assign *minimal permissions*** to the User so that it has enough permission to perform the function (eg `s3:PutObject` for the given bucket). Do not assign `s3:*` on every bucket! (Very bad for security.)
- On the on-premises computer, run `aws configure` (part of the AWS CLI) and enter the credentials that were provided when the IAM User was created

This will place the credentials in a `.aws/credentials` file on the computer. Never put credentials in your programming code! (Again, bad for security.)

If you are asking how to create an IAM User, please see: [Creating an IAM User in Your AWS Account - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html)